# Test for registration page in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm stuck for like 3 hours trying to find out why. The site I'm currently working on uses Mysql (deprecated) and I need to create registration form where users are required to answer a random test question pulled from the database before submitting the form. The database has [id/question/answer] columns.

I had written something like this:

```
$question_query = mysql_query("SELECT question FROM questions ORDER by RAND () LIMIT 1");
$question = mysql_result ($question_query, 0);

$answer_query = mysql_query("SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE question='$question'");
$answer = mysql_result ($answer_query, 0);
```

and then after all the checks

```
else {
$user_answer = $_POST['answer'];
if ($user_answer != $answer) {
$error = "Wrong answer";
}   
else {
$register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES(blablabla)")
or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: register.php");
}
```

When I hit submit it echos the $error = "Wrong answer".
However, when I have only one question row in the database it works perfectly fine. As if the $question_query runs a random select all over again when I hit submit or something and thus renders the answer to that question false. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Does the form submit to the same page? If so then yes, the queries will run again and generate a new question/answer. To be 100% sure though you need to add the entire file so there aren't any confusion about how it's structured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I have only one question row in the database it works perfectly fine.

That's because when you get a *random* element from a list of 1, it will always be the same element.

You're selecting a *random* question from the database and then comparing the answer of that question to the answer provided:

```
SELECT question FROM questions ORDER by RAND () LIMIT 1
```

So it's *unlikely* that the *random* question selected is going to be the same as the one which was previously asked.  And that likelihood decreases as the number of questions increases.  (50% chance with 2 questions, 25% chance with 4 questions, etc.)

When you originally show the question to the user, include in the form an identifier for the question.  For example, if the table has an `id` column then you'd include that in the form.  Something as simple as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questionId" value="<?php echo $someQuestionId; " />
```

Then when the form is posted the identifier would be available here:

```
$_POST['questionId']
```

You'd use that value to make *one* query to the database, getting the answer for the question with that ID.  Something like:

```
SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE id=$id
```

---

**Important Note:** Your current data access approach is *wide open* to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  You'll want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to better understand why this is a problem and how you can, very easily, correct it.

Comment: Wow, that's smart. Would never get to this on my own. Thank's a lot man!